# Angular Support For Azure AD B2C

Tags: angularjs, azure-ad-b2c

Azure AD B2C now supports SPAs. But is this supported by Angular? While implementing Azure AD (not B2C) I found a file `adal-angular.js`. I can inject its services, call its extended end points and get my way done.

Is there any file for Azure AD B2C? Or `adal-angular.js` works for Azure AD B2C too? Please correct me if anything I wrote above is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

`adal-angular.js` will only work for non-converged AzureAD apps (apps that are registered in the [Azure Portal AzureAD Blade](https://portal.azure.com)). AzureAD B2C apps are converged so this library will not help you.

AzureAD B2C does in fact support SPA's using the [open source library hello.js](https://github.com/MrSwitch/hello.js/).  Here is a [SPA code sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi). There is not currently any Angular code samples for AzureAD B2C, but as an oAuth 2.0 service you should be able to hook up almost any open source Angular oAuth2.0 library that supports implicit flow.

Answer (score 0):

We just released our solution to integrate Angular with AAD B2C: https://github.com/3DSemantix/angular-asp.net-core-aad-b2c

The "SPA code sample" from MS is a bit weird when I looked at it (refreshing the token feels hacky).